# Discrete toggle flip-flop simulation issue

Tags: transistors

I always wanted to have some ~100 MHz frequency divider at hand, and since I have some BC548's lying around I ran a quick Simulation with Pspice Student 9.1.

Source: electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html

[image]

A 20 MHz square wave input yields this:
[image: Toggle FF, 20 MHz input]

A quick look at the BC548 datasheet says it has a transit frequency of ~100 MHz,
so I'd say it can be done but I don't know why the simulation fails at higher frequencies.

Some analog Gurus know why ?

best,
Chris

Comment: You need to take a closer look at the signals on some of the other internal nodes of your circuit in order to understand what's going on. Come back here if you still have questions about the low-level details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a simulation issue I think, more of a circuit design issue.

You'll need to avoid saturation to get close to 100MHz. Try Schottky clamps on the transistors (eg. A [BAT54](http://www.vishay.com/docs/85508/bat54v.pdf) dual). The clamp diode is connected from collector to base to prevent saturation.

Also, you can study how ECL flip-flops work. ECL circuits are more like differential amplifiers and do not have switching transistors that saturate.

Of course you can simply buy a flip-flop that us guaranteed to work beyond 100MHz such as a [NC7SZ74](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/NC/NC7SZ74.pdf), which will toggle at 250MHz.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - for now, I'll stick to your flipflop recommendation. I had a gut feeling that using some random site's schematic wouldn't work - but then, that's some incentive to re-learn hybrid-pi, switching characteristics, differential resistance, how to read spec sheets ... and eventually, buy a copy of "The Art of electronics" :)   Happy Holidays !

Answer (score 0):

One part of the understanding is noting that you don't have an active pull up. You are using a 3.9 K ohm resistor(R4) to do all the heavy lifting.  When transistor turns off, R4 has to charge up all of the capacitances in transistor V5.

Thus you get what appears to be (and is) a waveform that looks like an RC time constant charging.

The fall time looks nice.   Definitely needs an active transistor to pull high :
Example :

[image]

As  @DaveTweed mentions, there are more things to look into.

+